# issue with submit in registration form when clicked there is nothing happen

Tags: laravel, forms

I have registration view for registration that is made by php artisan make:auth and when I fill the form and click submit button there is nothing happen

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
```

I haven't changed any thing in the form

Comment: <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">

and I haven't changed any thing in the form

Comment: put your code please

Comment: can you show  your error?

Comment: Please use config:cache or view:clear, and check it on private browser.

Comment: I tried view:clear and config:cache and open in private window but the proplem still exist